# Generating distinct groups based on vector/column pairs in R

Tags: r, grouping, distinct

SEE UPDATE BELOW:

Given a data frame with two columns (x1, x2) representing pairs of objects, I would like to generate groups where all members of each group are paired with all other members in that group. Thus far, I have been able to generate groups by showing all items in x2 that are paired with each item in x1, but this leaves me with groups where a couple of members are only paired with one other group member. I'm having a hard time getting off the ground with this one... Thanks in advance for any help you may have. Please let me know if I should edit this post as I am new to Stack Overflow and new to R coding.

```
x1 <- c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E")
x2 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "C", "B", "D", "E", "D", "E")

df <- data.frame(x1, x2)
```

### I would like to go from this df, to an output that looks like df2.

```
group1 <- c("A")
group2 <- c("B", "C")
group3 <- c("B", "D")
group4 <- c("D", "E")

df2 <- data.frame(cbind.fill(group1, group2, group3, group4, fill =   "NULL"))
```

**UPDATE:**

Given the following dataset....

```
x1 <- c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "B", "C", "F")
x2 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "C", "B", "D", "E", "D", "E", "F", "F", "F")

df <- data.frame(x1, x2)
```

.... I would like to identify groups of x1/x2 where all objects within said group are connected to all other objects of that group.

This is what I have thus far (I'm sure this is riddled with best-practice errors, feel free to call them out. I'm eager to learn)...

```
n <- nrow(as.data.frame(unique(df$x1)))

RosterGuide <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = n , ncol = 1)) 
RosterGuide$V1 <- seq.int(nrow(RosterGuide))
RosterGuide$Object <- (unique(df$x1))
colnames(RosterGuide) <- c("V1","Object")
groups_frame <- matrix(, ncol= length(n), nrow = length(n))

for (loopItem in 1:nrow(RosterGuide)) {

object <- subset(RosterGuide$Object, RosterGuide$V1 == loopItem)
group <- as.data.frame(subset(df$x2, df$x1 == object))

groups_frame <- cbind.fill(group, groups_frame, fill = "NULL")
}

Groups <- as.data.frame(groups_frame)
Groups <- subset(Groups, select = - c(object))
colnames(Groups) <- RosterGuide$V1
```

This yields the data frame 'Groups'....

```
     1    2    3    4   5    6
1    F    D    B    B   B    A
2 NULL    E    D    C   C NULL
3 NULL NULL    E    F   D NULL
4 NULL NULL NULL NULL   F NULL
```

... which is exactly what I am looking for, except that if you look at the original df, objects F and D are never paired, rendering group 5 invalid. Also, objects B and E are never paired, rendering group 3 invalid. A valid output should look like this...

```
     1    2    3   4   5 
1    D    B    B   B   A    
2    E    D    C   C  NULL
3   NULL NULL NULL F  NULL
```

Question: is there some way that I can relate the groups listed above in the 'Groups' data frame to the original df to remove groups with invalid relationships? This really has me stumped.

For context: What I am really trying to do is group items based on pairwise connections derived from a network of nodes where not all nodes are connected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way doing it in base `R` using `apply` and `unique`

```
df <- data.frame(x1, x2, stringsAsFactors = F)
df <- df[df$x1 != df$x2, ]
unique(t(apply(df, 1, sort)))

  [,1] [,2]
3 "B"  "C" 
4 "B"  "D" 
9 "D"  "E"
```

**`dplyr`**

```
df %>%
  dplyr::filter(x1 != x2) %>%
  dplyr::filter(!duplicated(paste(pmin(x1,x2), pmax(x1,x2), sep = "-")))

  x1 x2
1  B  C
2  B  D
3  D  E
```

**`data.table`**  (there might be another better way)

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, .SD[x1 != x2]][, .GRP, by = .(x1 = pmin(x1,x2), x2 = pmax(x1,x2))]

   x1 x2 GRP
1:  B  C   1
2:  B  D   2
3:  D  E   3
```

Comment: Thank you for your help nsinghs! I really appreciate your time. The solutions you propose work for this particular case, but I think the example dataset I provided is too limited to convey the full scope of the problem. I will edit the question with a more holistic view of the issue as well as some progress I have made.